# Email shows as "Cancelled" when triggered using civiRule

Tags: civimail, civirules

I have setup a civiRule to send out a email 5 mins after a contribution is added.
The event does get triggered properly but the email shows up as "cancelled" under user activity and no email is received by the users.
I verified the form email, template setting, everything looks correct but still no success in sending the emails.

Comment: exactly the same problem here.

Comment: actually it was a problem with the signing keys.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use [CiviCRM scheduled reminders](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/) to send emails? If you are still want to use Civi rule you should provide some screenshot of your settings so that we can check and provide some inputs